# Getting "Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance" error, aftrer I instaled "hardevine/shoppingcart" package

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I have installed the "hardevine/shoppingcart"-package in my laravel project, and I get the error bellow when i try to access the **product details**, after i updated the composer!

```
Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\MeDelivery\resources\views\partials\productdetails.blade.php)
```

My **ProductController** is:

```
public function detalheProduto($id)
{
    $produtos=DB::table('produtos')->where('id',$id)->get();
    return view('partials.productdetails',compact('produtos'));
}
```

And the **blade view** is:

```
@foreach($produtos as $value)
    <!-- property area -->
    <div class="content-area single-property" style="background-color: #FCFCFC;">&nbsp;
        <div class="container">

            <div class="clearfix padding-top-40">
                <div class="single-property-wrapper">

                    <div class="section">
                        <h4 class="s-property-title">Descrição</h4>
                        <div class="s-property-content">
                            <p>{{$value->info_pro}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: `dd` the collection in the controller and check what it returns.  and where are you trying to get the `id` property in the blade?? in your shared code you are just trying to get `info_pro` property.

Comment: add which line you are getting the error

Comment: I get this! Is showing all data I need show in my view... But, if i use the blade i get the error above! **Collection {#275 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#282 ▼
      +"id": 1
      +"nome_pro": "Tetracilina"
      +"codigo_pro": "014"
      +"preco_pro": 136
      +"info_pro": "Tetraciclina é um grupo de antibióticos naturais ou semi-sintéticos usados no tratamento de um amplo ▶"
      +"category_id": null
      +"image": "tetra.png"
      +"spl_price": 300
      +"stock": 10
      +"created_at": "2019-09-16 10:29:02"
      +"updated_at": "2019-09-16 10:29:02"
    }
  ]
}